# sorting fix with strings in excel(vba)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset that looks like this when sorted:

```
Abc0
Abc100
Abv15
Abc4
Abc700
```

I was wondering how can I make this sorted like:

```
  Abc0
  Abc4
  Abc15
  Abc100
  Abc700
```

Any ideas?

Comment: who is doing the sorting?

Comment: I am. I saved the sort as a macro for sort method Row# values A-Z.

Comment: So you want to sort a string partially lexicographically, up until it encounters the right-hand digit sequence and sort numerically on that part?

Comment: split the data into 2 columns (text and numbers) then sort the 2 columns (numbers within text). Note you will have to convert the text numbers to real numbers.

Comment: If you own the sorting algorithm then it's a simple thing for you to modify the sort predicate, as @Orbling specifies.

Comment: Do you always have 3 letters before the numbers?

Comment: Will the average string be more or less then 9 characters long?

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you have "Abv15" -- with a "v" -- in the first list and "Abc15" -- with a "c" -- in the second list.  The answer I posted will sort it with "Abv15" at the end because of the "v" vs. "c".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
'Return an integer which is greater than zero if the first string is "greater"
'than the second string, less than zero if the first string is "less" than the
'second string, and equal to zero if they are the same string.  It is assumed
'that both strings start with alpha characters and end with numeric characters.
Function CompareAlphaNumericStrings(First As String, Second As String) As Integer
    Dim arrFirstParts() As String
    arrFirstParts = SplitAlphaNumericString(First)
    Dim arrSecondParts() As String
    arrSecondParts = SplitAlphaNumericString(Second)

    Select Case StrComp(arrFirstParts(0), arrSecondParts(0), vbTextCompare)
        Case 0
            Dim intFirstNumeric As Integer
            intFirstNumeric = CInt(arrFirstParts(1))
            Dim intSecondNumeric As Integer
            intSecondNumeric = CInt(arrSecondParts(1))

            If (intFirstNumeric < intSecondNumeric) Then
                CompareAlphaNumericStrings = -1
            Else
                If (intFirstNumeric > intSecondNumeric) Then
                    CompareAlphaNumericStrings = 1
                Else 'they are equal.
                    CompareAlphaNumericStrings = 0
                End If
            End If
        Case Is < 0
            CompareAlphaNumericStrings = -1
        Case Is > 0
            CompareAlphaNumericStrings = 1
    End Select
End Function

'Split the provided string, which is presumably comprised of a set of alpha characters
'followed by a set of numeric characters, and return a two-element array
'containing first the alpha portion and second the numeric portion.
Function SplitAlphaNumericString(ToSplit) As String()
    Dim arrReturn(1) As String

    For i = 1 To Len(ToSplit)
        If (Not IsLetter(Mid(ToSplit, i, 1))) Then
            If (i > 1) Then arrReturn(0) = Left(ToSplit, i - 1) Else arrReturn(0) = "" 'If there is any alpha portion at all, grab it, otherwise empty string.
            arrReturn(1) = Mid(ToSplit, i) 'The rest should be numeric.
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    SplitAlphaNumericString = arrReturn
End Function

'Return true if the provided string is a single character and that character is a letter (A - Z or a - z).
Function IsLetter(TestChar As String) As Boolean
    If Len(TestChar) = 1 Then
        If (TestChar >= "A" And TestChar <= "Z") Or _
            (TestChar >= "a" And TestChar <= "z") Then
            IsLetter = True
        Else
            IsLetter = False
        End If
    Else
        IsLetter = False
    End If
End Function
```

You can use this in a whatever your favorite sorting algorithm is, e.g. bubble sort:

```
Function SortValues()
    For i = 1 To 5
        For j = 1 To 4
            Dim strFirst As String
            Dim strSecond As String

            strFirst = Sheets(1).Cells(j, 1).Value
            strSecond = Sheets(1).Cells(j + 1, 1).Value

            'If the first belongs AFTER the second, swap them.
            If (CompareAlphaNumericStrings(strFirst, strSecond) > 0) Then
                Sheets(1).Cells(j, 1).Value = strSecond
                Sheets(1).Cells(j + 1, 1).Value = strFirst
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

First enter the following two UDFs:

```
Public Function TextPart(sIn As String) As String
    Dim L As Long, LL As Long
    Dim sCh As String
    TextPart = ""
    For L = 1 To Len(sIn)
        sCh = Mid(sIn, L, 1)
        If sCh Like "[a-zA-Z]" Then
            TextPart = TextPart & sCh
        End If
    Next L
End Function

Public Function NumberPart(sIn As String) As Long
    Dim L As Long, LL As Long
    Dim sCh As String, temp As String
    For L = 1 To Len(sIn)
        sCh = Mid(sIn, L, 1)
        If sCh Like "[a-zA-Z]" Then
        Else
            temp = temp & sCh
        End If
    Next L
    NumberPart = CLng(temp)
End Function
```

Then in B1 enter:

=textpart(A1)  and copy down

Then in C1 enter:

=numberpart(A1)  and copy down

Then sort cols A,B,C first by B and then by C.

You should see:

[image]

Comment: Is it really faster to loop every character in the string for a numeric value, then it is to test for each numeric value (0-9) in the string? the ladder would only need 9 loops opposed to the first needed as many loops as there are characters.

Comment: Hi @user2140261  For REALLY long string you have a good point!